# How to freeze Path Data

Tags: wpf, xaml, freezable

We have many complex `Path`s in our WPF application. An example would be:

```
<Path Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Most of our Control Templates require extensive use of vector graphics and multiple effect are applied on these paths.

For performance reasons, we want to freeze the `Data` of these paths since it won't be changed. This syntax we're using creates a [`StreamGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and assigns data to it. `StreamGeometry` is freezable but how can we freeze it in our xaml?

Comment: The StreamGeometry is already frozen when it is created in XAML by Path Markup.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks. I thought so at first. But how can we see if an object is frozen at runtime to be sure? And any references on that matter?

Comment: @Clemens You're right. `Path.Data.IsFrozen` returns true.

Comment: You could check the `IsFrozen` property of the Path's `Data`. Can't quickly find any reference on MSDN though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"` attribute. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970057%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Summary from MSDN:

> Sets the IsFrozen state to true on the containing Freezable element.
>   Default behavior for a Freezable without the
>   PresentationOptions:Freeze attribute specified is that IsFrozen is
>   false at load time, and dependent on general Freezable behavior at
>   runtime.

Setting `IsFrozen` to true is exactly the same as calling `Freeze()` on an Freezable object.

In your case, you need to set the PathGeometry to be frozen.

```
<Path>
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"
            Figures="..." />
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I set that for the data? Doesn't `<Path PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" Data="..."/>` mean "Freeze the Path object"? `Path` is not freezable but its `Data` is.

Comment: See updated answer.  Edit: @Clemens comment points out that StreamGeometry is frozen by default when using the Data attribute markup.  I did not know this!  I'll keep this answer here in case someone isn't using the Data syntax.